# Where can I contact ROS developers for a collaboration project?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I want to integrate an Adroid app to a platform based on ROS.  I use freelancer and have not found anyone with the skillset.  Is there anyone here who could point me in the right direction to locate a pool of people (or person) who can offer consultancy and development services for ROS on a time and materials basis?

Many thanks in advance, Dataman.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112926/where-can-i-contact-ros-developers-for-a-collaboration-project?/) by [Dataman](https://answers.ros.org/users/10226/dataman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a good place to start:

http://osrfoundation.org/consultants-network/

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0